# First time add to cart show 0 items in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have used Woocommerce plugin for my shopping site and also using [Elessi Nasatheme](https://themeforest.net/item/elessi-woocommerce-ajax-wordpress-theme/20968615). When add item from product details page getting 0 items on cart bubble and pop also. Can anybody suggest me what is the main problem.

I am sharing my shop url: https://jalaj.aphroecs.com/booboo/product/hoodie/

Comment: Look at the error messages on the page when you click on add to cart. They say **Chest is a required field** and **Height is a required field** but those fields aren't visible so a person can not complete them. Sounds like you have a configuration issue.

Comment: You can check Custom Tailoring and fill both fields.

Comment: This is an issue related to your premium theme, and you should better contact the support of your theme author's pages instead. Please note that StackOverFlow don't handle any software support. Very sorry, but this question is off-topic for many reasons.

Comment: If custom tailoring is optional then those 2 additional fields can not be required/mandatory.

Comment: Now both are optional.

Comment: And now that they are optional things are working correct?